# Getting an error when saving a scss file in vs code

Tags: css, npm, visual-studio-code, sass

I am very new to sass and I used node-sass NPM package to compile scss files into the CSS format

This is the error I am getting when I save the file

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: D:/WEB Deveble: D:/WEB Deve Html and css practice/My Portfolio/scss/main.scember",
  "formatted": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: D:/WEB Deveble: D:/WEB Deve Html and css practice/My Portfolio/scss/main.soli\n"
}
```

But for some reason only sometimes I get this error and the other times the file compiles the perfectly
like this

```
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to D:\WEB Development\Advanced Html and css practice\My Portfolio\dist\css\main.css
```

this is my package.json
[image]

this is the error that is showing in my terminal
[image]

Can someone help me with this problem,
Thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the problem also might be in folders naming.

1. Delete file and create new one from the editor directly.
2. Remove **spaces** and **dashes** from all folder names throughout path.
3. Try to shorten the full path, by shortening the folder names.